# Text.Html vs Blaze.Html

Tags: haskell, blaze-html

I'm a bit confused which Haskell Html library to use.
People tend to recommend the use of libraries available available in the Haskell platform (which is the case of `Text.Html`), however everybody seems to use `Blaze.Html`.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: "People tend to recommend the use of libraries available available in the haskell platform" Really? I've never heard that. Many people, myself included, have aversions towards large dependencies, but blaze is super lightweight, at least compared to great beasts like lens. Also, `Text.HTML` hasn't been updated in 6 years, while blaze is regularly maintained.

Comment: It's on Haskell Wiki [http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program] and nobody seems to have corrected it.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: @Jeffrey: The question is more about "Haskell platform" being what it's claiming to be. And so far the question hasn't attracted opinionated answers or spams.